# Resolutions of graded modules over positively graded polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, graded-rings, graded-modules

I am looking for a proof of this fact: *Let $W=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be a positively graded polynomial ring. Every graded free resolution of a finitely generated $W$-module $M$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of the minimal graded free resolution and a trivial complex, that is, a direct sum of complexes of the form
$$0\to W(-p)\xrightarrow{1}W(-p)\to0.$$*

I found a proof of almost the same result, where the positively graded ring $W$ is replaced by a quotient $R=S/I$, where $S$ is a *standard graded* polynomial ring and $I$ is a homogeneous ideal. But I cannot understand if I can deduce from this the result I need. Is it so?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "positively graded"?

Comment: I mean that $\deg(x_i)>0$ for all $i$. I have been reading some results and I just cannot figure whether some proofs that hold when $\deg(x_1)=\dots=\deg(x_n)=1$ still hold in this more general case or not. For example, it seems to me that Nakayama's Lemma is still valid in this context. Am I right? Thank you

Comment: I don't think your result is restricted to polynomial rings or graded $k$-algebras. It must hold for ($\mathbb Z$-)graded rings, in general.